# python reduce initializer error

Tags: python, functional-programming, reduce

I'm trying use python's reduce in a similar way to racket's foldl, but when I run the following code:

```
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x.append(y), [1,2,3], [])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Can you please help explain the error and suggest a fix?

Comment: `reduce` expects a function argument that **returns something**, which `append` doesn't...

Answer (score 5):

That's because `append()` doesn't return anything.

You can do:

```
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y], [1,2,3], [])
```

Comment: thank you so much! My array has tuples where the 2nd value is an integer that I want to add. I JUST couldn't figure out why  ```functools.reduce((lambda x, y: x[1]+y[1]), arr)``` wasn't working like it did in python 2.7. Finally, this worked -  ```functools.reduce((lambda x, y: x+y[1]), arr, 0)```